# How to aggregate user logs based on email domain name in ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, tokenize

I have a Json field called `UserId` in each document. I would like to create a new field that contains only the email domain.

Example:

```
{
    "FirstName" : "John",
    "LastName" : "Smith",
    "Email" : "jsmith@gmail.com"
}
```

How do I create an analyzer and a `copy_to` field that will let me have an additional field: `EmailDomain : "gmail.com"`

I know that the tokenizer will be the `@` char, but I don't know how to create the analyzer, etc to do the rest of this.

Thank you!

Comment: if you use tokenizer then it will create [jsmith , gmail.com] not only  gmail.com here is useful link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/analysis-simplepatternsplit-tokenizer.html

Comment: if you want only EmailDomain : "gmail.com" then add EmailDomain  field in your mapping and index it again